# How to use in_category in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to pull out all the posts with portfolio projects as a category.But this code won't work for me.

```
 <?php if(have_posts()):
           if(in_category('Portfolio Projects')):
              while(have_posts()):
                    the_post(); 
    ?>
         <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    <?php 
                   endwhile;
                 endif; 
             endif; 
     ?>
```

Comment: can you tell me that this is a custom taxonomy if it is then what is your `portfolio-category`'s taxonomy ... or `portfolio-category` is a taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible in the order you wrote it. The $post object is not set up by the time you want to decide whether it's in a category or not.

Look here, what **the_post()** does: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/

The code below should work:

```
<?php
     if(have_posts()):
        while(have_posts()):
            the_post();
            if(in_category('Portfolio Projects')):
?>
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php 
            endif; 
        endwhile;
    endif; 
?>
```

But I think it would be much better to only query for posts that are in the category you want - and not query for all posts, and then decide (works with posts and categories - no custom things):

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => 'Portfolio Projects',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

This is the link to the function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

After getting the **$post_array** you have to iterate through that and display them how you want.